# Fast Synonyms' Calculations in Matlab

Tags: nlp, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

ok I have now got code in Matlab, which compute synonym in less than a second...

```
clc
clear all
close all
warning off
text = 'good';

Doc = actxserver('Word.Application');
X = invoke(Doc,'SynonymInfo',text);
Synonyms = get(X,'MeaningList');
```

But now issue is, its computing it for one word. How can I use it in an array? Like if I have file of words? Please guide

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and organize the words in a cell array:

```
words = {'good', 'bad', 'apple'};

Doc = actxserver('Word.Application');
X = cellfun(@(word) invoke(Doc,'SynonymInfo',word), words, 'UniformOutput', false);
Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) get(X,'MeaningList'), X, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Now you can access `Synonyms{3}`, for example, to retrieve the synonyms of "apple".

Comment: Thanks @Rafael

It is working but if I use loop like:

for i=1:length(words)
Doc = actxserver('Word.Application');
X = cellfun(@(word) invoke(Doc,'SynonymInfo',word), words(i), 'UniformOutput', false);
Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) get(X,'MeaningList'), X, 'UniformOutput', false);
end

It finds synonyms of only 3rd one.. as words are three but I want to find synonyms of all three words in this loop

Please Guide!

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You just have to call the code I proposed **one time**, not in a loop. Then you can do something like this to retrieve all synonyms: `for i = 1:length(words), disp(Synonyms{i}); end` Or just type `Synonyms{:}` on Matlab to see all results.

Comment: Can I display synonyms of words to extent =2? I mean if synonyms of a word exceed 2 they must only display 2 synonyms and ignore others.

Comment: Sure. Just add this line below the code: `Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) X(1:min(2, numel(X))), Synonyms, 'UniformOutput', false)`. The `min(2, ...)` argument regulates the maximum number of words allowed. You can change it to any value you want.

Comment: Sorry for bothering... Can I display word also with synonyms? In that case, which changes will I do? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to include the original word in the list of synonyms?

Comment: Yes .. like if word is /good', I must get good, and its synonyms

Comment: Sute, just add this line and your Synonyms cell array will contain the word as the first entry: `Synonyms = cellfun(@(X) [words{X}; Synonyms{X}], num2cell(1:numel(words)), 'UniformOutput', false)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind support :)

Comment: if Synonym of a word does not exist it writes [], cant it leave it empty cell?

Comment: That's weird. I ran all commands in a sequence (including those on coments) and when a synonym doesn't exist, the cell contains only the original word (not []).

Comment: Sorry for bothering again @Rafael.. 

Can you please guide in server issue please? i.e. Doc = actxserver('Word.Application');
you know this server is created each time synonym calculated. I am calling this function in other file where 5000 words are placed in an array and this function is created for each and at one stage fails and halts the system too..

is there any way to make synonyms calculation more better and efficient or this server issue decrease prominence?

Comment: You only need to call that line once.